# How to compare dataset's row and column with the datagridview's row and column?

Tags: vb.net

I am doing vb.net development. First of all i have 10(row)*7(columns). I am trying to compare it with dataset's row and column with the datagridview's row and.And trying to firing update query for update records. I done with update query.Now, with the position of 9 no row it will going normal and when it will reach at the position no 10 of row then it will throws an following error. click on this image description you will get error message.

[error][1]

```
Try 
   Dim rowindex As Integer = 2 
   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridViewl.Rows For index = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1 
     If row.Cells(index).Value.ToString <> 
       DS.Tables("Login").Rows(rowindex - 1)(index).ToString Then 
       Dim query As String = "update Login set Emp_Name='" + 
       row.Cells("Emp_Name").Value.ToString _ + "',Emp_Code='" + 
       row.Cells("Emp_Code").Value.ToString _ + "',Email='" + 
       row.Cells("Email").Value.ToString _ + "',Address='" + 
       row.Cells("Address").Value.ToString _ + "',MobileNo='" + 
       row.Cells("MobileNo").Value.ToString _ + "',Password='" + 
       row.Cells("Password").Value.ToString + "' where L_ID='" + 
       row.Cells("L_ID").Value.ToString + "'" 
       Sqlexe(query)
    End If 
  Next rowindex += 1 

Catch ex As Exception  
     MsgBox(ex.ToString) 
End Try
```

Comment: Please do not post a screenshot of the code but paste the code into the editor. You can format it as code with the toolbar

Comment: can you post the error as well? **NOTE:** writing sql queries like this leads to [**sql injection**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0926bc/sql-injection/).